# is there a way to cd into a directory based on the last characters?

Tags: bash, cd-command

I have directories that begin with `164` but they differ based on the last few digits. I would like to cd into a directory based on the last few digits if not the last digit itself, say `9` vs `8`. The directories are unique in the last digits. Is it possible to do so? Autocomplete lists a number of possibilities when I begin with the first digits `164`.

Comment: I'm using zsh with oh-my-zsh and have configured autocomplete to match the characters at any point in the file/directory name, not only at the beginning. Not an answer since the question is tagged bash.

Answer (score 33):

With Bash, yes, you can use wildcards:

```
cd /path/to/*9/
```

(replace `9` with however many digits you need; you can drop `/path/to/` if you’re in the directory containing all the `164...` directories).

You need to ensure that the expression is specific enough to resolve to a single directory, otherwise `cd` will change to the first directory specified in its arguments (in Bash before version 4.4), or fail with an error (Bash 4.4 and later built with `CD_COMPLAINS`). (Take care with Zsh or Ksh which have a two-argument form of `cd` which you might invoke accidentally, albeit only if your current path contains the first argument.)

You can also tab-complete after typing the command above, before executing it; if more than one directory matches, your shell will list them all.

Answer (score 18):

If they are ***actually*** distinct except for the last few digits, you can use a wildcard in the cd command, e.g.,

```
cd 164*8
```

(and if they are not actually distinct, the shell will remind you of this by producing an error message).

Answer (score 6):

You could do something custom.

```bsh
mycd() {
    local ng=$( shopt -p nullglob )
    shopt -s nullglob
    local status

    local matches=( *"$1"/ )  # directories ending in the parameter
    case ${#matches[@]} in
        0) echo "no directory ends with $1" >&2; status=1 ;;
        1) cd "${matches[0]}"; status=$? ;;
        *) echo "multiple directories end with $1" >&2; status=1 ;;
    esac

    $ng   # restore the previous nullglob setting. specifically unquoted
    return $status
}

mycd 89  # cd to the subdir ending with 89
```

That can be extended to use a select statement, when there are more than one matching dir, to allow you to choose which one you want.